# Why use Angular 2 inside an ASP.NET project?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

There is an ASP.NET Core with Angular 2 template in Visual Studio 2017. But why use it? Wouldn't it be better to use ASP.NET to serve JSONP to Angular and develop the Angular Frontend completely separated (I would prefer Visual Studio Code)? Looks like better separation of concerns to me.

The Angular App (a true SPA, no other pages with Razor or the like required) could then be hosted with any webserver. Or are there benefits in using Angular inside the ASP.NET project that I (as an Angular but not ASP.NET newbie) am missing?

Comment: Since my question was flagged as opinion based, I guess that there is no fact based answer to it and therefore it does not make much of a difference if I use Angular with or without ASP.NET so per Ockham’s razor I will use Angular without ASP.NET - thank you, opinion flaggers, how can I accept your answer?

Comment: *“The Angular App could then be hosted with any webserver”* – But why? The point with the Angular template is that you already have all bits there necessary to host a SPA. It’s just the same as if you did the thing in Node, just that the server backend is ASP.NET Core here. If you believe choosing ASP.NET Core here has any impact on *how* you develop your application (e.g. what editor to use), then you apparently haven’t even tried it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons why you would still want to have the power of a server for other tasks than serving JSON data. Here are two:

Server-side rendering - The UI for your startup page can be pre-built and sent to the client before your Angular app is sent or starts running.

Microsoft Identity - You can use the already existing framework for authentication by just clicking a button during project creation. You still need to use round trips to the server for registration and login. Why not use what already exists?

Comment: I haven't seen a template for Angular and ASP.NET Core 2 in Visual Studio that allows clicking a checkbox during creation to get Authentication. Only have seen disabled Authentication box. Is there a way to do this that I don't know about?

Comment: I meant to say the "Change Authentication" button when using any of the Web App or Web API templates. You can create a Asp.Net Core app and then add Angular to it.